# Redefine echo for several scripts by calling a script that redefines echo

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have scripts A, B, C, etc. that I execute independently. I want to redefine how echo works for all scripts I am using.

I made the following script, `preamble.sh`, that I call from each script A, B, C:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Change the color of our output
# TODO: How to redefine echo for the parent caller?
PURPLE='\033[1;35m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color
function echo() { builtin echo -e '\033[1;35m'$0'\033[0m'; }

unameOut="$(uname -s)"
case "${unameOut}" in
Linux*) machine=Linux ;;
Darwin*) machine=Mac ;;
CYGWIN*) machine=Cygwin ;;
MINGW*) machine=MinGw ;;
*) machine="UNKNOWN:${unameOut}" ;;
esac
echo "[Running on ${machine}...]"
```

When I do `bash preamble.sh` from another script, all I get is

```
preamble.sh
```

in purple (the color that I want echo to use in each script A, B, C, etc.).

I guess what ends up happening is echo is redefined correctly within `preamble.sh` but this is not how I expected it to work. When I call `bash preamble.sh`, `preamble.sh` gets executed but instead of telling me what machine it runs on, it just prints `preamble.sh` in purple because that must be the argument `$0`.

I realize I might be doing something that is not possibly to do directly.

How do I achieve what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Note that the `function` keyword is only in bash for compatibility with ancient ksh and shouldn't be used in new code. See https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Comment: Also, name libraries using bash syntax with `.bash` extensions, not `.sh` (which is for shell libraries compliant with POSIX sh; whereas things that are executables rather than libraries shouldn't have extensions at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments to a function are `$1`, `$2`, ...

You want:

```
function echo() { builtin echo -e '\033[1;35m'$1'\033[0m'; }
```

not:

```
function echo() { builtin echo -e '\033[1;35m'$0'\033[0m'; }
```

Whether inside a function of not, `$0` will remain the name of the script itself.

Edit: For your other question, you would need to run the script within the current shell for the changes to persist. You can do this using either

```
source preamble.sh
```

or

```
. preamble.sh
```

This is necessary since by default, the script will run in a new shell and any variables, functions, etc you define will not be visible.

Comment: That solves one problem. So now I see `running on Linux` as expected in purple. How do I redefine echo for scripts A, B, C, etc. It still prints everything else in the usual colors so the new definition of `echo` isn't persisted.

Comment: Try `source preamble.sh`

Comment: That worked! I don't know why I didn't think to do that because sometimes I do `source ~/.bashrc` in lieu of restarting my terminal.

Comment: Note also that `echo -e "$foo"` is better replaced with `printf '%b\n' "$foo"`. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/3113 for an in-depth discussion.